# Solving negative domain trigonometric equations with unit circle

Tags: trigonometry

How would you solve a trigonometric equation (using the [unit circle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5NcGo.png)), which includes a negative domain, such as:

$$\sin(x) = 1/2, \text{ for } -4\pi < x < 4\pi$$

I understand, that the sine function is positive in the 1st and 2nd quadrants of the unit circle, so to calculate the solutions in the positive domain it's:

$\theta$ (1st quadrant), $\pi - \theta$ (2nd quadrant), $2\pi + \theta$ (returning to the 1st quadrant), $3\pi - \theta$ (returning the the 2nd quadrant).

Though, how do you traverse the unit circle for the negative domain, is there a [pattern like for the positive solutions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5NcGo.png) $(\theta,  \pi-\theta, \pi+\theta, 2\pi-\theta$, and so on)

Comment: $\sin$ is $2\pi$-periodic, so there's no conceptual difference between negative and positive translations of $[0,\,2\pi)$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\sin x=\frac12\iff x=\begin{cases}\frac\pi3+2k\pi\\{}\\\frac{2\pi}3+2k\pi\end{cases}\;,\;\;\;\;\;k\in\Bbb Z$$

And now just solve the inequalities on $\;k\;$:

$$\begin{cases}-4\pi<\frac\pi3+2k\pi<4\pi\iff -\frac{13}3<2k<\frac{11}3\iff -\frac{13}6<k<\frac{11}6\\{}\\-4\pi<\frac{2\pi}3+2k\pi<4\pi\iff -\frac{14}3<2k<\frac{10}3\iff -\frac73<k<\frac53\end{cases}\iff$$

$$k=-2,-1,0,1,$$